# Issuing debugging with gdbserver

Tags: c, netbeans, gdbserver

I am using the gdbserver plugin in Netbeans trying to attach to a remote debugging session.  However I get an error: "inappropriate ioctl for device."  I am able to remote debug by launching gdb from the terminal but I would like to be able to use Netbeans for debugging.

Comment: How are you starting gdbserver, and what are you putting into this attach dialog (http://wiki.netbeans.org/GdbServer)?

Comment: Yes, I get the error when I click ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I was able to fix it by running the "debugger" "Using GDB Debugger" on my project. It failed, because my project doesn't run on this machine. But after doing this, I was able to successfully run the "debugger" "gdbserver".